# are html elements like OOP classes?

Tags: html

I may be naive in thinking that html elements have the characteristics of OOP objects.  In particular in working with a UL element I am assuming that its LI sub-elements are in a collection which I can access as List.items.  I have been searching for documentation which describes the properties of html elements but no-joy.  Can someone direct me to the kind of documentation that I seek?

Comment: Unfortunately your question is phrased in such a way that it is off-topic. You are not allowed to ask for off-site resources. However, if you were to rephrase your question - or even simply remove the last sentence, it should be valid. Then the core of your question is, can HTML elements be compared to OOP elements or not. And in which way. (Though I'd advise you to add what you think and what you have found so far. Here on SO we expect some sort of input from the topic starter.)

Answer (score 2):

This isn't all too far off from how it actually works. The difference is that the naming scheme of these properties is as generalized as possible, to keep them the same across elements. Some elements have extra properties (`canvas`, `iframe` and `object` and a bunch of others with some kind of functionality)

The `list.items` you are thinking of would in reality be `list.childNodes` and would work for any other element as well. Mozilla has great documentation on the [HTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul) and [JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes) aspects of this. The whole MDN is worth exploring if you're new to web development.

Answer (score 0):

Html elements are nowhere near to OOP classes. According to some of paradigms of OOP object must support : Encapsulation, Polymorphism, Inheritance, Abstraction.

You can't do that with html elements directly that's why they don't 'belong to object oriented world'. Even using javascript you cant make them behave like C# classes.

HTML is a declarative markup language not an object oriented one (this has changed a little however with Html 5 appearance). But still.

Read about javascript DOM elements tree and how it works. Google it and you'll find a lot of good information.